# How to access trailing metadata from python gRPC client

Tags: grpc

Here is how I am sending the metadata from server.

```
def DoSomething(self, request, context):
    response = detection2g_pb2.SomeResponse()
    response.message = 'done'
    _SERVER_TRAILING_METADATA = (
                                ('method_status', '1010'),
                                    ('error', 'No Error')
                                )
    context.set_trailing_metadata(_SERVER_TRAILING_METADATA)

    return response
```

Here is what I tried:

```
res = _stub.DoSomething(req) 
    print (res.trailing_metadata())
```

In this case I get Attribute Error  object has no attribute 'trailing_metadata'. I  want to know way to access the trailing metadata in the client side.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but while the patient is on the table: I think you should write `response = detection2g_pb2.SomeResponse(message='done')` rather that the separate construction and mutation statements that you have in your current code. Then also just elide the local field by writing `return detection2g_pb2.SomeResponse(message='done')`?

Comment: Make sense. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I apologize that [we don't yet have an example illustrating metadata](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/issues/368) but you can see [here how getting the trailing metadata on the invocation side requires using `with_call`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/c7520d0d8f1c3833f9a1c04c953e272a120f31c4/src/python/grpcio_tests/tests/unit/_metadata_code_details_test.py#L197-L198) (or `future`, but that may change the control flow in a way that you don't want changed, so I think that [`with_call`](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.with_call) should be your first choice). I think your invocation-side code should look like

```
response, call = _stub.DoSomething.with_call(request) 
print(call.trailing_metadata())
```

.